# Imprimir um número inteiro que denota o número de elementos repetidos no vetor

Tags: c

Fiz o código para imprimir o número de vezes que elementos se repetem no vetor, porém ele falha no primeiro caso de teste e passa nos demais. Alguém pode me apontar onde estou errando, por favor!!

Segue aqui os casos de teste:

**Teste 1:**

Entrada

```
8
1 2 1 3 5 3 2 1
```

Saída

```
4
```

**Teste 2:**

Entrada

```
8
1 2 4 5 7 8 3 6
```

Saída

```
0
```

**Teste 3:**

Entrada

```
8
1 2 4 5 7 2 3 6
```

Saída

```
1
```

**Teste 4:**

Entrada

```
8
1 2 4 5 7 8 2 6
```

Saída

```
1
```

Segue o código abaixo:

```c
#include <stdio.h>  
   
int main()  
{  
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    
    int A[n];
    int size = 0;
    int value = 0;
    //enquanto conseguir ler valores antes de chegar no fim do arquivo
    while(scanf("%d ", &value) > 0) {
    A[size++] = value;
    }
    
    int count = 0;  
    //Procura por elementos repetidos  
    for(int i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {  
        for(int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {  
            if((i != j) && A[i] == A[j])  
                count++;
        }  
    }  
    
    
    printf("%d", count);
    
    printf("\n");
    
    return 0;  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consegui, galera! Segue o código:

```c
#include <stdio.h>  
   
int main()  
{  
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    bool repete = false;
    
    int A[n];
    int size = 0;
    int value = 0;
    //enquanto conseguir ler valores antes de chegar no fim do arquivo
    while(scanf("%d ", &value) > 0) {
    A[size++] = value;
    }
    
    int count = 0;  
    //Procura por elementos repetidos  
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {  
        for(int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {  
            if(A[i] == A[j] && repete == false) {
                count++;
                repete = true;
            }
        }  
        repete = false;
    }  
    
    
    printf("%d", count);
    
    printf("\n");
    
    return 0;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

você colocou um espaço em branco depois do especificador de tipo de dado na leitura com scanf :

```
scanf("%d ", &value);  /// espaco em branco
do
{
    scanf("%d", &value);  /// sem espaco
}while( value != 0 );
```

e isso causa essa falha , e outra coisa é que esse while como está será um loop etherno , e só vai sair dele quando scanf falhar na leitura , ao digitar uma letra por exemplo , então melhor usar o **do / while** , e também no loop  j  de comparações não precisa comparar se  i   é igual  a  j  , pois nesse caso nunca serão iguais , . ,

Comment: Consegui resolver, obrigada!

Comment: Esse espaço não interfere na leitura: https://ideone.com/juto3d - sem contar que a condição de parada não é quando o valor é zero... Aliás, a forma que a @LarissaPereira fez é mais adequado (verificar o retorno de `scanf`, que retorna a quantidade de itens que foram corretamente lidos)